# Apache2.4.10 on Ubuntu returning Internal server error on running CGI scripts

Tags: server, apache2, python, cgi

I am running  Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) and I was trying to run CGI scripts with the following configurations.

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

With the following

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

###################################################################
#########     Adding capaility to run CGI-scripts #################
ServerName localhost
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
```

And the `/etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        #<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        #   AllowOverride None
        #   Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        #   Require all granted
        #</Directory>

        ## cgi-bin config
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
            <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI 
            </Directory>

    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I have my `cgi-script` in the directory `/var/www/cgi-bin`

with the contents in `hello.py` and made it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgitb
    cgitb.enable()    print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

I also did `sudo a2enmod cgi` as suggested here [Apache2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 won't execute Python cgi file. The site displays python code instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547391/apache2-4-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-wont-execute-python-cgi-file-the-site-displays-pyt)

When I try to run the script by going to http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py I am getting a `500 Internal Server error`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Saw the error logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and saw that there is an indentation error because of the `cgitb.enable()`.

Corrected the indentation and now its running fine.